# nginx + django múltiples dominios sin redirecciones

Tags: django, nginx

Tengo un servidor con nginx que deriva las peticiones a django.
Dentro de django tengo la siguiente estructura:

app/

```
organizaciones/
               urls.py
               views.py
               templates/
```

El diseño atiende con los mismos views y templates, que con parámetros desde los views se le pasan a los templates se logra tener sitios asociados a diferentes organizaciones.

Cuando se invoca midominio.com/organizaciones/organizacion1 se muestra la home de organizacion1 y asi con otras organizaciones.

Quisiera que la organizacion1 pueda tener su propio dominio y que por la URL organizacion1.com se muestre lo que está en midominio.com/organizaciones/organizacion1 pero sin cambiar la URL en el navegador (sin hacer redirección).

Entonces, si se escribe organizacion1.com/nosotros se muestre lo que está en midominio.com/organizaciones/organizacion1/nosotros

Probé con diferentes proxy_pass en nginx, pero se rompe cuando se la URL es organizacion1.com/nosotros

Probé con un custom middleware en django, pero lo que hace es una redirección a través del método httpresponseredirect.

¿Cómo se puede lograr esto?
Gracias